# Can I use the Amazon seller API to query orders from multiple different merchants from the same IP?

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api

Can I use the Amazon seller API to query orders from multiple different merchants within the same IP?

for the seller center in browser, IP will be restricted. What qualifications do I need to develop a program that can be used by multiple merchants? can any registered Amazon Developer do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, see this question on the Selling Partner API GitHub docs:
https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/issues/651

> For call API on behalf of other seller you need following.
>
> 1. Generate access token
> 2. Generate authorization Code
> 3. Exchange LWA authorization with refresh token
> 4. Generate access token
> 5. Call API like Order API / report API